# How can I delete all the files in a directory but not the directory itself in Rust?

Tags: rust

How can you delete all the files in a directory without deleting the directory itself?

I thought this would work but it gives an error:

```rust
for entry in std::fs::read_dir("tmp/my_items") {
    std::fs::remove_file(entry);
}
```

```
the trait `AsRef<std::path::Path>` is not implemented for `ReadDir`
```

Comment: [std::fs::remove_file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.remove_file.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the directory isn't being used, watched, or anything else that prevents it being deleted. Then you could just delete the whole directory using [`fs::remove_dir_all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.remove_dir_all.html) and create it immediately after using [`fs::create_dir()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.create_dir.html), i.e.:

```rust
use std::fs;

let path = "tmp/my_items";
fs::remove_dir_all(path).unwrap();
fs::create_dir(path).unwrap();
```

---

Otherwise, you seem to have confused what [`fs::read_dir()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html) actually returns.

It returns a `Result<ReadDir>`, which need to be unwrapped. However, while [`ReadDir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.ReadDir.html) does implement [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.ReadDir.html#impl-Iterator), it doesn't actually produce paths. It actually produces `Result<DirEntry>`, which also need to be unwrapped and still isn't a path. To get the actual path you have to call [`path()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html#method.path).

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::path::Path;

fn remove_dir_contents<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> io::Result<()> {
    for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        fs::remove_file(entry?.path())?;
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    remove_dir_contents("tmp/my_items").unwrap();
}
```

If the directory doesn't only strictly contain files, then you need to check the file type and remove directories and their contents as well.

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::path::Path;

fn remove_dir_contents<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> io::Result<()> {
    for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        let entry = entry?;
        let path = entry.path();

        if entry.file_type()?.is_dir() {
            remove_dir_contents(&path)?;
            fs::remove_dir(path)?;
        } else {
            fs::remove_file(path)?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: what is the io::Result<()> type?

Comment: The various `fs` and `io` functions return an [`io::Result<...>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html) to tell whether they succeeded or failed. So in case `remove_dir_contents` fails, then it will return the error. Otherwise if no errors occurred, then `Ok(())` is returned, in short, nothing.

Comment: do I need to import that type specifically? Tried running with std::fs and got  ```use of undeclared crate or module io```

Comment: I forgot to include the use declarations. I've updated the example :)

Comment: in your `if entry.file_type()?.is_dir()` branch, you call `remove_dir_contents` recursively. which does what we want, i think. but i'm wondering if at that point we might as well do `fs::remove_dir_all(path)`?

Answer (score 2):

`read_dir` returns an iterator over `io::Result<DirEntry>` objects. `DirEntry` is not a path itself (it's got many separate features, and they didn't implement silent coercion to `Path` possibly to avoid confusion), but it has [a `.path()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html#method.path). Something like this (based on the example given for `.path()`) should work:

```
for entry in std::fs::read_dir("tmp/my_items")? {
    let entry = entry?;
    std::fs::remove_file(entry.path())?;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65573339/5299417) has pointed out, `std::fs::read_dir` returns [`ReadDir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.ReadDir.html) (inside a `Result`), which is an iterator over [`DirEntry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html)s (inside `Result`s).

In a similar style to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65573340/5299417), you could just remove the directory and all its contents and then recreate the directory in one go with [`Result::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then).

```rust
use std::fs;

let path = "tmp/my_items";
fs::remove_dir_all(path).and_then(|_| fs::create_dir(path))?;
```