# How to remove all the content of a dir with Rust comand in linux

Tags: rust

normally to delete all the file and subfolder of a directory i would use like this

```
rm -rf backup/nosva/credentials/*
```

but i'm doing it via rust code

```
Command::new("rm")
    .arg("-rf")
    .arg("backup/nosva/credentials/*")
    .spawn()
    .expect("rm command failed to start");
```

and he says he can't find that folder.

i also  tried

> std::fs::remove_dir_all

but it removes the entire dir

Comment: The `*` (called a globbing pattern) is processed by the shell and expanded by it to multiple arguments passed to `rm`. You will need to either do the same (i.e. list the files yourself and add them individually to the arguments) or run the command through a shell (e.g. `Command::new ("sh").arg ("-C").arg ("rm -rf backup/nosva/credentials/*")…`)

Comment: The solution is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573245/how-can-i-delete-all-the-files-in-a-directory-but-not-the-directory-itself-in-ru