# Directory not empty (os error 39) when I using rust to delete direactory recursive

Tags: rust

When I use this code to delete directory recursive:

```
use std::{io, fs, path::Path};

fn main() {
    let result = remove_dir_recursive(Path::new("/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/logs"));
    if let Err(err) = result {
        println!("{}", err);
    }
}

pub fn remove_dir_recursive(dir_path: &std::path::Path) -> io::Result<()> {
    if dir_path.is_dir() { 
        for entry in fs::read_dir(dir_path)? { 
            let entry = entry?;
            let entry_path = entry.path();
            
            if entry_path.is_dir() {
                remove_dir_recursive(&entry_path)?; 
            } else {
                fs::remove_file(entry_path)?; 
            }
        }
        fs::remove_dir(dir_path)?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

sometimes will get this error:

```
Directory not empty (os error 39)
```

I have tested this method in local machin and it works fine. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this issue? I have already tried to switch to `remove_dir_all` like this:

```
pub async fn del_project_disk_file(proj_id: &String) {
    if proj_id.is_empty() {
        error!("delete project id is null");
        return;
    }
    let proj_dir = get_proj_base_dir(proj_id).await;
    let result = fs::remove_dir_all(Path::new(&proj_dir));
    match result {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(e) => {
            error!("delete project from disk failed,{}", e)
        }
    }
}
```

still did not fixed this issue.

Comment: This probably means a file was created while iterating through `read_dir`. You should just use https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.remove_dir_all.html

Comment: I have switch to remove_dir_all but still facing this error.@drewtato

Comment: Have you confirmed that something is adding files to it while you're trying to delete it? If so, the error is expected and you should handle it appropriately, maybe by trying again or logging it and continuing.

Comment: How about running the famous `rm -rf` command? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74209364/how-to-remove-all-the-content-of-a-dir-with-rust-comand-in-linux Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573245/how-can-i-delete-all-the-files-in-a-directory-but-not-the-directory-itself-in-ru

Comment: the `rm -rf` is a little bit dangerous, I am trying to switch the sync std delete folder to tokio async delete, no error output until now. @Raeisi